# payment transactions and order table?

Tags: mysql, database-design, payment

What is the best way to handle payment transactions to the database?

Here is what I came up with:

**Orders Table**

- OrderID (primary key)**
- MemberID (FK)
- OrderTotal
- Status (Pending, Processing
  Completed)
- Paid (0, 1)

**Payments Table**

- PaymentID (primary key)
- OrderID (related to Orders table)
- Date
- Transaction Status

For example, if there is two payment transactions from OrderID-123 in the Payments table.

One is **Decline** and other one is **Sucesss**

If there is a row of **Sucesss**, then Orders.Paid will become 1

Or what is better solution?

Comment: Don't forget to associate the PaymentID with its corresponding OrderID

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Decline and success are not enough in my experience. Among colorful use-cases, you may experience successful payments pending clearing of funds (e.g. e-checks), refunds (made by you), reversals (made by the customer/api provider), partial refunds/reversals (e.g. the dog's toy but not his food, within the same order), reversed refunds/reversals.

Not to mention the variety of other cases inherent to subscriptions, e.g. subscription upgrades and downgrades, subscription changes, cancellations, cancelled cancellations, locked, and what not.

Needless to say, issues become even thornier if you ever need to deal with affiliate payments, user-less invoices, different billing/shipping contacts, resellers, etc.

The precise answer depends on your specific requirements, obviously, but I've found that you're almost always better off starting with a model that satisfies the rigors of T-ledger accounting (i.e. debit/credit with a chart of accounts), and then working your way up towards your specific products.

Comment: +1 for Denis - especially with respect to the T-ledger notion.  Records related to payments and even status changes to the owed amount should all be written once and never updated.  This gives you an audit trail of all of the transitions.  Another wrinkle you might need to consider is payment application, i.e. one payment covers (parts of) multiple orders.  This will definitely be important if you have payment for statements (as opposed to invoices).